# Linked list :: hash table :: Valgrind error :: Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value

Tags: c, linked-list, hashtable

Need help again.

I've got my linked list working. It copies a list of words from a file into a linked list.

Now I want to make a hash table so that all words starting with the letter 'A' go into a bucket [0] of linked list.

The code I've written; it seems to work for small and large lists but Valgrind shows points to errors.

```
-----CODE-----
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

typedef struct node     //struct for linked list
{
    char* word;
    struct node* next;
}
node;

int findhash(char firstletter)      //this function returns a hash value for first alphabet of every word
{
    int hash = 0;

    if(isupper(firstletter))
        hash = firstletter-'A';
    else hash = firstletter-'a';

    return hash;       
}

int main (void)
{            
    char* dictfile = "small";

    FILE* dict = fopen(dictfile, "r");

    if (dict == NULL)
        return 1;

    char oneword[47];      //to store the word from fscanf()

    node* hashtable [30];       //creates a hashtable        

    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)        //gives an index to every element in the hash table
    {
        node* temp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
        temp->next = NULL;           
        hashtable[i] = temp;
    } 

    while ((fscanf (dict, "%s", oneword)) > 0)
    {                                        
        node* temp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));            
        char* tempword = (char*)malloc(strlen(oneword)+1); //gives me a new pointer to store the string (as pointed out by Antione)            
        strcpy(tempword, oneword);

        char firstletter = tempword[0];

        int hash = 0;
        hash = findhash(firstletter);      //returns an index for the first alphabet of the word                  
        temp->word = tempword;

        //printf("%s\n", temp->word);     //prints the value (just for debug)

        temp->next = hashtable[hash];            
        hashtable[hash] = temp;             
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
    {           
        node* temp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
        temp = hashtable[i];
        while (temp != NULL)    //loop to print the linked list 
        {           
            if (temp->word != NULL)    //**THIS IS WHERE VALGRIND IS POINTING THE ERROR TO BE**
            {
                printf("%s\n", temp->word);
                temp = temp->next;
            }
            else break;
        }   
    }

    printf("\n");
    fclose(dict);

    printf("SUCCESS!!\n");      

}
```

Where am I going wrong?? Please help

```
    -----VALGRIND ERROR-----
    jharvard@appliance (~/Dropbox/pset5): valgrind ./tempeol
==11035== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==11035== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==11035== Using Valgrind-3.10.0.SVN and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==11035== Command: ./tempeol
==11035== 
antione
==11035== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==11035==    at 0x80488CA: main (tempeol.c:68)
==11035== 
beer
bear
caterpillar
cat
google
root

SUCCESS!!
==11035== 
==11035== HEAP SUMMARY:
==11035==     in use at exit: 582 bytes in 74 blocks
==11035==   total heap usage: 75 allocs, 1 frees, 934 bytes allocated
==11035== 
==11035== LEAK SUMMARY:
==11035==    definitely lost: 480 bytes in 60 blocks
==11035==    indirectly lost: 102 bytes in 14 blocks
==11035==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==11035==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==11035==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==11035== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==11035== 
==11035== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==11035== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==11035== ERROR SUMMARY: 30 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Valgrind shows 30 errors. My hashtable is size 30. So feel the problem should be somewhere there. But I can't figure out why?

Comment: Are you sure fscanf (dict, "%s", oneword) actually does what you want?

Comment: `node* temp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));temp = hashtable[i];` : malloc'd memory was rewrited.

Comment: @MichałSzydłowski Why?? It is copying the words beer, bear.... Root; from the file 'dict' into the linked list properly.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I don't understand why. I am just duplicating hashtable[i] and copying hashtable[i] into temp; so that I can traverse & print the linked list. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: E.g. `hashtable[i]` has pointer (address 0xXXXX), `temp` set to return value of malloc(address 0xYYYY), `temp = hashtable[i]` : temp set to 0xXXXX, then 0xYYYY rewrite by 0xXXXX, memory 0xYYYY cannot access (ensure memory by malloc). it means MEMORY LEAK.

Comment: `node* temp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node)); temp = hashtable[i];` = instant memory leak in two lines of code. Anyone coming from reference-based languages like Java or C# should take note: `type *var = some-alloc-func();` followed immediately by `var = something-else;` is flat-out wrong virtually 100% of the time. From what i see that loop is only reporting anyway, so there is no earthly reason to be allocating anything in the first place. Nor is there any reason to initialize the hash table with anything *other* than `NULL` in each slot.

Comment: Thanks @BLUEPIXY and @WhozCriaig. I understand how it rewrites memory. But I require temp to be equal to the hashtable[i] to print the linked list. would `node* traverse = hashtable[i];` prevent the leak?

Comment: @jzz honestly, i'd do something more [like this](http://pastebin.com/GuRYHHxH).

Comment: @ WhozCraig Woa. Thanks. I'm still trying to understand some of the things you did there. I think I know where my code is wrong. I'll try and fix that. Then use your solution if I'm still stuck (otherwise it's too easy). Never used memcpy, size_t... Still a lot to learn. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your initialization of the hashtable entries isn't initializing the field `word`, that is what valgrind is complaining about.

Additionally your code seems to have other problems. E.g the `malloc` in the line just before is immediately overwritten and thus this memory leaks. Also the return of `malloc` shouldn't be cast. Avoid casts whenever you can, think of casts as "casting a spell". As long as you don't know what that does, avoid it.

Comment: Thanks @Jens Gustedt. But if I initialise word, I'd end up with segmentation faults. Yes, I understand that now about malloc, I'll try and fix it and see if it still works.